# InvalidOperationException when i try to retrieve a password from database, "Invalid attempt to read when no data is present."

Tags: c#, sql-server

This is my code, I need to retrieve `LoginPassword` from the database

```
public partial class frmPassword : Form
{
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=WORKSTATION\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=TPSystem;Integrated Security=True");

    public frmPassword()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnUpdatePassword_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        frmLogin login = new frmLogin();
        string UserN = login.UName;
        string Pass;
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Login_Password FROM AdminLogin WHERE Login_Username = '"+UserN+"'", connection);

        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            reader.Read();

            Pass = reader["Login_Password"].ToString();

            if (tbOldPassword.Text == Pass)
                MessageBox.Show("Password matches");
            else
                MessageBox.Show("Password wrong");
            reader.Close();
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Report", MessageBoxButtons.AbortRetryIgnore, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        finally
        {
            connection.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

I got this error on execution:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
>   occurred in System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: Invalid attempt
>   to read when no data is present.

Comment: Which line does this happen on?

Comment: @gunr2171 this is the line " Pass = reader["Login_Password"].ToString();"

Comment: Nor a solution, but _strongly_ consider changing to parameters instead of concatenating SQL - _especially_ when dealing with tables with passwords.

Comment: your query isn't returning anything

Comment: It sounds like you are passing in a login name that does not exist in the database, and `Read()` is failing.

Comment: You should check `if (reader.Read()) { ... }`. -- Another thing: for the love of all that's good and holy, please do *NEVER EVER* store passwords in plain text! Please read http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/09/youre-probably-storing-passwords-incorrectly.html and http://blog.moertel.com/posts/2006-12-15-never-store-passwords-in-a-database.html and http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/04/speed-hashing.html

Answer (score 4):

The `reader.Read()` methods returns a boolean to indicate if anything was in fact read - you're not checking that at all....

Change your code to:

```
if(reader.Read())
{
    Pass = reader["Login_Password"].ToString();

    if (tbOldPassword.Text == Pass)
            MessageBox.Show("Password matches");
    else
            MessageBox.Show("Password wrong");
}
```

If nothing was read, I guess your user doesn't exist - I'm not sure what you want to do in that case.... up to you

But ***please*** tell me you're ***NOT*** storing passwords in **clear text** in your database!!!!

Comment: You could mention that [`if (reader.HasRows)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.hasrows(v=vs.90).aspx) would also be useful to (pre)check if there are rows at all. I like to use it first because it doesn't advance the reader to the next/first record, so it doesn't have any side-effects.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: I never use `.HasRows` - does it have any benefit over just calling `.Read()` and checking the result, if there are no rows??

Comment: I find it just more readable to use `HasRows` if i want to know if there are records at all. The other benefit is that you can use it without to remember that it will advance the reader to the next record like `Read` does. And it won't break the code if you expect multiple rows sometime(`while(reader.Read()){...}else{}` doesn't work).

Answer (score 1):

It seems that there is no entry in the database for the username you are checking. Please check if thereader returns a result:

```
public partial class frmPassword : Form
{
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=WORKSTATION\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=TPSystem;Integrated Security=True");

    public frmPassword()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnUpdatePassword_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        frmLogin login = new frmLogin();
        string UserN = login.UName;
        string Pass;
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Login_Password FROM AdminLogin WHERE Login_Username = '"+UserN+"'", connection);

        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while(reader.Read())
            {
            Pass = reader["Login_Password"].ToString();

            if (tbOldPassword.Text == Pass)
                MessageBox.Show("Password matches");
            else
                MessageBox.Show("Password wrong");
            }
            reader.Close();
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Report", MessageBoxButtons.AbortRetryIgnore, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        finally
        {
            connection.Close();
        }
    }
}
```